# SAML authentication for Application on Localhost

Tags: localhost, saml, adfs

I would like to use SSO with SAML for an Application. During development we would like to test this on localhost.

When I was working with OIDC I would simply create a redirect URL for localhost in the IDP (we use ADFS).
My colleague in charge of the ADFS just informed me we could not do that for SAML since SAML would interpret the redirect ULR relative to the ADFS. (and thus create a redirect loop)

Can anyone tell me a good way to use SAML with a remote ADFS on localhost?
Or do we need to set up a local IDP during development?

Thank you, 
Junge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure https://localhost URLs for the SAML relying party endpoints in ADFS. The only restriction is that you must use https rather than http. ADFS will send the SAML response, via the browser, in an HTTP Post to your assertion consumer service endpoint (eg https://localhost:44360/SAML/AssertionConsumerService).